# Java inline predicates: cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, predicate

Sorry for the simple question - I come from the .NET stack. All I want is an inline Predicate. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong:

```
toReturn = Iterables.find(articles, a -> a.toString().equals(input));
```

It tells me that 'a cannot be resolved to a variable'. I'm assuming that I just need an import or that I'm using an old version of Java? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you on Java 8?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm trying to find out, but I'm not sure of the easiest method. Any advice?

Comment: How are you compiling your source code? Do a `java -version` on the command line if you are sure you are using the same JDK.

Comment: If you haven't installed the Early Access Release of Java 8 then you probably won't be using Java 8; the final version hasn't been released yet.

Comment: Hmmmm.. I guess that "1.7.0_45" is prehistoric?

Comment: No, that's Java 7. They removed the "1." at the beginning from the name with Java 5, just not everywhere.

Comment: Ah, so I was closer than I thought! Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible in Java 7 or earlier; it exists in Java 8 and later though. With Java 7 and prior you are able to use [lambdaj](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) to similar effect though. It would look something like this:

```java
toReturn = Iterables.find(articles, new Predicate<Object>() {
    public boolean apply(Object item) {
            return item.toString().equals(input);
    }
});
```

You can check out more details [here](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures).

**Edit:**
As pointed out in the comments, there are alternatives. As you're using [Iterables](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) I'm guessing you would want a [com.google.common.base.Predicate](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html) which can be defined very similarly:

```java
toReturn = Iterables.find(articles, new Predicate<Object>() {
    public boolean apply(Object item) {
            return item.toString().equals(input);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // check whether the other object is also a Predicate
    }
});
```

Comment: Guava is also an acceptable alternative that provides such functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the details and alternative implementation! Again, I figured this might be the issue but just wanted confirmation from the community. I'm assuming that my version of Java is less than 8.